# Is there a way to shorten a file path on Mac (Python) and lessen the dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, os.path

I already tried to use the os.path function.

For example, I have this file path:

```
/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file1.csv
```

And I want to shorten it to

```
/file1.csv
```

So that I can then use the pd.read module to read the file. For example, I'd like to do this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file3.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file4.csv")
df5 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file5.csv")
df6 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file6.csv")
df7 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file7.csv")
df8 = pd.read_csv("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file8.csv")
```

However, obviously 2 things are in my way:

1. The file path name being so darn long
2. The amount of dataframes I have. I'd like to put them all together and read them all at the "same time" so I don't have to iterate through each one and make the code more extensible

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "shorten the path", are you asking how to move a file from one path to another?

Comment: Where is your python file locate in your pc?

Comment: Why do you want this? You cannot access the file using the path `/file1.csv`. If you want some kind of relative path, it must not start with `/`.

Comment: You can define the root of the path as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead manually of defining variables like that, you can use a for loop to define,

and append the variables into a list.

```
df = []
amt = 8 # The amount of properly labeled csv files
for n in range(amt):
    d = pd.read_csv(f"/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file{n+1}.csv")
    df.append(d)
```

If you want to call `df3`, you can call `df[3]`, if you want `df5`, call `df[5]`, etc.

You can also use the `glob` module:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob("/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file*.csv") # List all the csv file in the Experiment folder that begins with 'file'
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use the glob function to instead do this for files that have different start names, for example files with the names Controlfile1, Controlfile2, Testfile1, Testfile2, and then do it for them all? Thanks.

Comment: You can change `"/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file*.csv"` to `"/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/*.csv"` to list *all* the csv files in `Experiment`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.join(os.path.split(r'/Users/GSteve_105/Documents/sites/Docs/Experiment/file1.csv')[1],'')` will do it.

Comment: That will give `file1.csv`, not `/file1.csv`.

Comment: @JohnGordon good point! You could add it back using ```os.path.join(filename, '')```. I updated above.

Comment: Or you can just add the `/` by overriding using this code `shorten = "/"+os.path.split(path)[1]`

Comment: @HamzaAnis "/" presumes the OS is Mac though.

Comment: If you want it to be more generic then you can use `os.path.sep` and it should be like this `shorten = os.path.sep+os.path.split(path)[1]` so for windows it would be `\file1` and for Mac and Linux it would be `/file1`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get in the current directory or let's say one directory up from the current one you could use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
```

Simply put, go into that file directory

```
sys.path.append('path/to/Experiment/')
```

so that when manipulating the csv you can reference to it like somefunction("file1.csv") without the need to specify the absolute path.